# Handling unicode names in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unicode

I want to convert all my data in a DataFrame to uppercase. When I start conversion from column names I get this error:

Code:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(target_processed_directory + filename)
# check sheet names
print(xl.sheet_names[0])

# sheet to pandas dataframe
df = xl.parse(xl.sheet_names[0])

# make whole dataframe uppercase
df.columns = map(str.upper, df.columns)
```

Error :

```
TypeError: descriptor 'upper' requires a 'str' object but received a 'unicode'
```

Answer (score 4):

When using Pandas you'll want to avoid `for` loops in Python, and you'll usually want to avoid `map()` as well.  Those are the slow ways to do things, and if you want to build good habits, you'll avoid them whenever you can.

There are fast vectorized string operations available for Pandas string sequences.  In this case, you want:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.upper()
```

Docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html

Comment: maybe you think `df.columns = df.columns.str.upper()` ;)

Comment: @jezrael: Fair enough, I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using list comprehension instead of mapping `str.upper`.

```
df.columns = [c.upper() for c in df.columns]
```

In Python 2.7, the distinction between strings and unicode is preventing you from applying a string method to a unicode object, despite the fact that the names of the methods are the same.